# Fields parameter - builder is gone?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

A month ago there was another interface to the google API where we could 'build' the fields parameter from a very handy popup. Where can we find it now?

Comment: After the Google APIs Explorer was updated, "Try this API" for testing APIs is used. Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, "Try this API" has no function for creating the fields parameter. From this situation, I created the fields builder for Google APIs. Is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/FieldsBuilderForGoogleAPIs